# Draw lines on JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, graphics2d

I am trying to make an rpg using swing (yes it is stupid I agree, but I am doing this for learning rather than actual working product). And currently I am working on each character stat.

I have a JPanel, and I would like to draw a line.

My intention is to have something similar to this
[image: The middle part is JPanel]

The left side is a JPanel that has two components, table 1, and JLabel.
Right side is also JPanel that has it's own elements but that is another story.

My question is that I would like to create a jpanel that would only have an image, and that image will be two lines going to the corners in relation to the selected element in the table.

But unfortunately I do not know how to go about drawing custom image on the JLabel. Can anyone suggest a way of going about drawing my own lines and everything on a JLabel? I have looked at a lot of questions, but they show how to draw already created image onto the JLabel, but I would liek to draw my own stuff (just the two lines).

Comment: For those thing I'd preffer the window builder plugin for eclipse or similar IDE. 
Its way much easier to build such things than really hard coding it.

Comment: I'd put a JPanel in the center and draw on that. (You can nest these components/containers like crazy.) You'll need to translate the row top and bottom to the parent JPanel's coordinates, then translate those to the center JPanel, but from there it should be a cinch. (And you might find the Box class handy for laying out table 1/child JPanel/table 2 inside the parent JPanel._

Comment: Are you learning swing or gaming ? IMHO Swing is awful to start programing. I suggest you to check LWJGL if Swing is not your target.

Comment: I am learning swing. And I find it easiest to learn something by writing a game using it since games usually tend to cover every aspect. I have tried using LWJGL and it is good, however I like simplicity when it comes to graphics like I did here https://github.com/Quillion/GameEngine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can anyone suggest a way of going about drawing my own lines and everything on a JLabel?

Draw to the `Graphics2D` of a `BufferedImage`.  Display the image (in an `ImageIcon`) in the label.

### E.G.

1. [Drawing text to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6296381/418556).
   [image]
2. [Drawing a border](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9772978/418556) (animated).
   [image]
3. [Another text demo.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13440543/418556), this one using scaling & fading.
   [image]
4. Oh, and here's [one with simple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10628553/418556) (..and dots, ..and it is animated).
   [image]

---

> I am trying to make an rpg using swing (yes it is stupid I agree, but I am doing this for learning ..

I don't think it is stupid at all.  Swing components are the only way to go if the choice is Swing or AWT.  Not only is the toolkit much richer (show me the AWT equivalent of `ImageIcon`, `JTree`, `JTable`,..) but has double buffering by default, and is directly **built on** the AWT.  I stressed that last part because it is often the case with games, where we override paint and 'go for it' - paint every pixel.

Once that is done, it is typically 'all AWT'.  The examples I posted use no AWT Components, yet all use a `BufferedImage`, some use `GlyphVector` or `AffineTransform`, either `Graphics` (when I' feeling lazy) or `Graphics2D` (for those wonderful rendering hints..).

But taking it a step even further and a 'Swing' splash screen or full screen window is also pure AWT.

For the clickable/editable components, use Swing.  For custom rendering, and corner cases like the splash or FSW, reach for the AWT classes.